# What is the difference betweend pandas.Series.items() and pandas.Series.iteritems()?

Tags: python, pandas, documentation

As you can see the documentation pages for [Series.items()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) and [Series.iteritems()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) are identical. Is it a mistake? Is one method outdated but kept for backward compatibility?

Most importantly, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Series.iteritems()` just calls `Series.items()` under the hood, see source code below:

```py
def iteritems(self) -> Iterable[tuple[Hashable, Any]]:
    return self.items()
```

[Pandas Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/series.py#L1691-L1693)

As a result, you should be fine to use either, although it appears `Series.items()` is preferred.